# How to enable 3D in VMware Player?

Tags: unity, virtualization, 3d, effects, vmware-player

I want to test Unity in a VM using VMware Player. I have already enabled 3D acceleration in the Display options and I have VMware Tools installed. However, when I try to run Unity or when I try to enable effects in appearance menu, it doesn't activate. Jockey says there is only one video driver available, which is enabled already.

I don't want to use VirtualBox.

Comment: I am not sure mutter works in a virtual machine. You might have to wait for the compiz re-write.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I guess I will have to wait before jumping into the Unity bandwagon :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think VMware Player supports OpenGL 3D for linux as yet. Linux support may come in future versions [probably the next one]. Compiz will definitely not work.

Only Directx windows runs on full throttle. Compiz-windows-clones[so called] work neatly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, even compiz-based Unity is unlikely to run in a VM (I asked about this at UDS and was told compiz doesn't run on VMs.)

Comment: compiz usually works on Virtual Box

Comment: Right, Compiz works fine in VirtualBox, I did so some days ago (Maverick guest on Maverick host).  Unity crashed though, apparently because it uses some 3D function that is unimplemented in the Chromium driver (that's the VBox 3D driver, not the browser or the OS from Google).

Comment: [How to get Compiz to work in VirtualBox.](http://askubuntu.com/q/10519/935)

Comment: Compiz works in Virtualbox, but you won't have any window borders if using seamless mode: http://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/6167