# "Desktop effects could not be enabled" in VMware

Tags: 10.10, video, vmware, effects

I am running on a Windows 7 64 bit host.
I'm use with VMware Player.

Ubuntu 10.10.

And, i get to Visual Effect, and when i press "normal" i get this error:

> Desktop effects could not be enabled

and if i press: **compiz**:

> compiz (core) - Fatal: Software
>   rendering detected. compiz (core) -
>   Error: Failed to manage screen: 0
>   compiz (core) - Fatal: No manageable
>   screens found on display :0.0

What i can to do?

Answer (score 2):

Vmware player doesn't support OpenGL on Linux yet, according to [How to enable 3D in VMware Player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10609/how-to-enable-3d-in-vmware-player) You could try [the lastest VirtualBox](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/heads-up-unity-working-with-the-lastest-virtualbox/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Did you installed/activated your driver for the graphics card?

If not go to **System -> Additional Drivers** and activate the driver for your graphic card.

Comment: Hey, I'm installed the vmware-tools, and i get the vmware drivers. so i get the "VMware Virtual Machine Communication interface".

What i can to do for that?

Do u want any other commands from me?