# Forced into "Classic" interface under VMWare Fusion

Tags: vmware

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 under VMWare Fusion on my macbook pro. The first time I logged in, there was a message, something like "Unable to run Unity because your hardware is not supported, Ubuntu will now switch to the classic interface" (Not exact message)

And then (and every time I log in) Ubuntu starts with a version 10 like interface and after sometime (~20 sec) switches to a real "classic interface"

This is when I log in:
[image: Login]

Immediately after I log in:

[image: Immediately after log in]

And in "sometime" (~20 to 30 sec):

(I did have the time to open the home folder, but I had to do it quickly)

[image: In Sometime]

1. Is this normal?
2. When Ubuntu says "Classic" interface, is this what it means?
3. I understand there may be special h/w requirements for Unity, but the version 10 desktop should be the fallback right?
4. Should I do some additional configurations somewhere?

(I have Ubuntu 10 on VMWare and it does work with the default desktop interface, albeit with the "No Effects" option)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even in the latest version update for [VMWare Fusion 3.1.3 for Mac](http://www.vmware.com/support/fusion3/doc/releasenotes_fusion_313.html) they claim to support Ubuntu up to version 10.04. only. There was some improvement in 3D support but this may only be true for Windows or Mac OS.

See also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/10609/3940).

If you need to run Ubuntu 11.04 with Unity supported you may want to try out [Virtual Box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17937/how-can-i-run-unity-in-a-virtual-machine/18556#18556).

In case the [theme is not set](https://askubuntu.com/q/21305/3940) properly run the following line in a terminal in the guest Ubuntu:

```
 sleep 5; ps -aef | grep gnome-settings-daemon | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill -9; sleep 2; gnome-settings-daemon; killall nautilus
```

Comment: Did try VirtualBox. I get a similar problem. The new Ubuntu interface opens, but with the old "classic" icons: http://imgur.com/hM1T9

Comment: This is [bug #574296](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/574296) see edit for workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Your second image is the normal "Classic" mode. Apparently your gnome-settings-daemon dies after 20 to 30 seconds, so you are left with the ugly default theme. You can hit Alt+F2 and enter `gnome-settings-daemon` to start it again. And/or look in the .xsession-errors file in your home directory to find why gnome-settings-daemon crashes.

Comment: Alt+F2 corresponds to some specific command? Nothing happens when I hit that, is there any alternative?

Comment: Alt+F2 should open a "run program" dialog. You can also open a terminal, it should be in the last item of the Applications menu.