# Why is Ubuntu booting in 2D mode on VMware?

Tags: 11.10, unity-2d

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on VMware, and now when I boot Ubuntu, it takes me directly to a 2D session. Anything I'm missing here that would prevent it from loading the 3D desktop?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/10609/how-to-enable-3d-in-vmware-player

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable 3D options in the vmware settings?
Considering its a VM, why do you need a 3D desktop?